# Upload file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads

Tags: php, uploads

I know it has been asked over and over again on the internet and i spend hours digging deeper into the web. But the no answer so far.

Why we get this error when you upload a file
`The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads`

1. I tried various file persimission on folders and files in the ftp.
2. Tried a fresh install WP.
3. I tried this code `define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );`
4. I tried adding the path in the `wp/options.php` location for upload_path.
5. I created the upload folder manually, because when i installed WP the `wp-content` folder does not have any folder named `uploads`

But nothing so far..

**Local Server**
There is no issue so far in the local server.

I am just a beginner and learning WordPress from scratch. The only issue i got stuck is this file upload thing.

Can anyone help me!

Comment: Whatever user your webserver runs as must have `write` access to the `wp-content/uploads` directory in order to upload files. You may have to consult your hosting company for assistance.

Comment: @PatJ i tried all the permission, and nothing seems to working. Alternatively iam using an external URL to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error while preparing an [AWS ec2 Bitnami micro-instance configured for WordPress](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007IP8BKQ).  This approach requires the command-line, so please launch a terminal-session and begin via SSH into the deployed production.

1. `cd` into the application document-root:

   `/home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs:`
2. Execute the below command to identify the Apache web-server:

   `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`

   Revealing `daemon` in this case, as captured within the terminal-output screenshot below:

   [image]
3. Ultimately, the below-command remediated the error; users should now have the ability to successfully media-upload content via the WordPress Content Management system/admin-panel:

   `sudo chown -R daemon:daemon wp-content`

I recommend the following dox for guidance regarding the Linux-commands referenced herein:

- [Finding out what user Apache is running as?](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as/133932)
- [what does this line mean on my ps aux ../apache2 -k start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338577/what-does-this-line-mean-on-my-ps-aux-apache2-k-start)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i found it that you have set the permission level in the hosting service provider's folder settings. Once it is done. The folder was created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Permissions were correct, there was enough storage.

What fixed it for me was deleting the month folder (08 in my case) and when re-uploading image, website recreated the folder and it worked fine :)